# Display a variable in a path()

Tags: twig

**What I have :** a variable called `url` that contains a string and that is sent to the view by controller.

**What I want :** I must have the following url at the end: https://example.org/url

**What I tried :** `<a href="{{ path('{{ url }}') }}">Go to URL</a>`
and some stuff.

Of course, it doesn't work.
Can someone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<a href="{{ path(url) }}">Go to URL</a>
```

If you put something inside quotes when you are inside twig delimiters it will be considered as a string, here you want to evaluate the variable `url`, so you simply have to put the name of the said variable and it will be evaluated this way.